# React component re-renders due to multiple styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native

I am facing a rendering issue when I pass multiple styles like so:

`<StyledComponent style={[styles.styleOne, styles.styleTwo]} />`

If the component StyledComponent is contained in re-renders, StyledComponent will re-render as well, even if the props do not change.

I am aware that if a parent component calls setState, then it's children will re-render regardless of the childs own props actually changing. I tried to utilize PureComponent and React.memo. However, my child components are still re-rendering. **It seems that the issue is the way I am sending down styles.** If I pass down one style as so:

`<StyledComponent style={styles.styleOne} />`

The PureComponent/React.memo works. However, if my component is styled as so:

`<StyledComponent style={[styles.styleOne, styles.styleTwo]} />`

then it re-renders every time.

**This is because I am instantiating a new array every render** of the parent component and the PureComponent/React.memo cannot pickup that those are the same styles.

So my question is, how can I use multiple styles on a component without having to write a custom shouldComponentUpdate on each of my children components? The renders are noticeably slowing my app's performance, as I am working with older Android devices, so I would like to minimize the renders needed.

Here is a snack that demonstrates this:
https://snack.expo.io/@tnortman/styles-r-stupid

Comment: Why dont you declare the styles array as a constant outside your render function.Assuming they are not going to change.

Comment: I can do this and found it to already work, but I think the chief concern is PureComponent does not catch this case. The React Native docs even recommend using [styles.styles, styles.styles2] syntax: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style

Comment: PureComponent only does a shallow comparison of props. It's not intended to catch this case.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to implement a custom shouldComponentUpdate, then you need to ensure that the array passes a `===` check. There are a couple possibilities for this, depending on how or if it can change. If it never changes, then that's the simplest: just create the array once up front, and then reference it. For example:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.Create({
  styleOne: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  styleTwo: {
    padding: 40,
  },
});

// Note that this line is not in render
const combined = [styles.styleOne, styles.styleTwo];

// ...

// in render:

<StyledPureComponent style={combined} />
```

If its possible for it to change, then you'll need to add some code for managing that. Most likely, i'd create a memoized function that produces the array, and only recalculates if something relevant has changed. For example, here's an example that sometimes includes style2, and sometimes doesn't, based on a prop:

```
// Just an example; you could use a different library or implement it yourself
import memoize from "memoize-one";

const combineStyles = memoize((shouldIncludeStyleTwo) => {
  const styles = [styles.styleOne];
  if (shouldIncludeStyleTwo) {
     styles.push(styles.styleTwo);
  }
  return styles;
});

// ...

<StyledPureComponent style={combineStyles(this.props.something)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the styles array out into an instance variable of the class and pass the reference via the props.  That way it isn't a new array each render.